# Fast summing of subarrays in Python

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, numba

I have a data cube a of radius w and for every element of that cube, I would like to add the element and all surrounding values within a cube of radius r, where r < w. The result should be returned in an array of the same shape, b.

As a simple example, suppose:

```
a = numpy.ones(shape=(2*w,2*w,2*w),dtype='float32')
kernel = numpy.ones(shape=(2*r,2*r,2*r),dtype='float32')
b = convolve(a,kernel,mode='constant',cval=0)
```

then b would have the value (2r)*(2r)*(2r) for all the indices not on the edge.

Currently I am using a loop to do this and it is very slow, especially for larger w and r. I tried scipy convolution but got little speedup over the loop. I am now looking at numba's parallel computation feature but cannot figure out how to rewrite the code to work with numba. I have a Nvidia RTX card so CUDA GPU calculations are also possible.

Suggestions are welcome.

Here is my current code:

```
for x in range(0,w*2):
    print(x)
    for y in range(0,w*2):
        for z in range(0,w*2):
            if x >= r:
                x1 = x - r
            else:
                x1 = 0
            if x < w*2-r:
                x2 = x + r
            else:
                x2 = w*2 - 1
            
            if y >= r:
                y1 = y - r
            else:
                y1 = 0
            if y < w*2-r:
                y2 = y + r
            else:
                y2 = w*2 - 1

            if z >= r:
                z1 = z - r
            else:
                z1 = 0
            if z < w*2-r:
                z2 = z + r
            else:
                z2 = w*2 - 1

            b[x][y][z] = numpy.sum(a[x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2])

return b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple version of your code so that it works with numba. I was finding speed-ups of a factor of 10 relative to the pure numpy code. However, you should be able to get even greater speed-ups using a FFT convolution algorithm (e.g. scipy's fftconvolve). Can you share your attempt at getting convolution to work?

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def sum_cubes(a,b,w,r):
    for x in range(0,w*2):
        #print(x)
        for y in range(0,w*2):
            for z in range(0,w*2):
                if x >= r:
                    x1 = x - r
                else:
                    x1 = 0
                if x < w*2-r:
                    x2 = x + r
                else:
                    x2 = w*2 - 1

                if y >= r:
                    y1 = y - r
                else:
                    y1 = 0
                if y < w*2-r:
                    y2 = y + r
                else:
                    y2 = w*2 - 1

                if z >= r:
                    z1 = z - r
                else:
                    z1 = 0
                if z < w*2-r:
                    z2 = z + r
                else:
                    z2 = w*2 - 1

                b[x,y,z] = np.sum(a[x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2])
    return b
```

EDIT: Your original code has a small bug in it. The way numpy indexing works, the final line should be

```
b[x,y,z] = np.sum(a[x1:x2+1,y1:y2+1,z1:z2+1])
```

unless you want the cube to be off-centre.

Assuming you do want the cube to be centred, then a much faster way to do this calculation is using scipy's uniform filter:

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter
def sum_cubes_quickly(a,b,w,r):
    b = uniform_filter(a,mode='constant',cval=0,size=2*r+1)*(2*r+1)**3
    return b
```

A few quick runtime comparisons for randomly generated data with w = 50, r = 10:

- Original raw numpy code - 15.1 sec
- Numba'd numpy code - 8.1 sec
- uniform_filter - 13.1 ms

Comment: OK, thanks. I had not found any significant speedups with njit, but possibly that was because the print was not working and so it seemed to hang. Maybe the print was the issue?

Comment: For scipy, I was trying this:
 
kernel = numpy.ones(shape=(2*r,2*r,2*r),dtype='float32')

b = convolve(a,kernel,mode='constant',cval=0)

Does that make sense? I will look into fftconvolve.

Comment: I added an example with scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve which I believe is equivalent to my three nested loops. Unfortunately it does not seem to be much faster. Which is surprising because scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter is very fast and does something more complex.

Comment: Yes, uniform_filter solved the problem! It reduced my smallest calculation from about 3 hours to 14 seconds, or a 750 times speed up! I can now tackle much larger problems.